# MFC Resizing dialog and child window paint problem

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, parent-child, resize

When I resize parent dialog (resizing border), child dialog is not painting correctly. Child dialog is partially hidden behind the border of parent dialog. If i make dialog bigger, revealed part of child dialog isn’t painted. But when i make it even bigger, child dialog paints to the previous border position. I tried my best with invalidating and redrawing dialogs but I can’t make it appear correctly.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add WS_CLIPCHILDREN style to the parent dialog.